# Count unique string variants

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, countif

There could be quite a simple solution to this, but I am trying to find the number of times a unique variant (i.e. non-duplicates) of a string appears in a column. However this string is only part of the text contained in a cell, and not the entire cell. To illustrate:

```
EuropeSpainMadrid
EuropeSpainBarcelona
AsiaChinaShanghai
AsiaJapanTokyo
EuropeEnglandLondon
EuropeSpainMadrid
```

I would like to find how many unique instances there are of a string that contains "EuropeSpain". So using this example, I would find that a variant of "EuropeSpain" appears only twice (given that the second instance of "EuropeSpainMadrid" is a duplicate).

A solution to this is to use pivots to summarise the data and remove duplicated; however given that my underlying dataset changes often this would require manual adjustments and corrections. I would therefore like to avoid adding any intermediate steps (i.e. PivotTables, other data sets etc) between my data and the counts.

**UPDATE:** I now understand to use wildcards to solve the first part of my question (counting the occurrences of "EuropeSpain"), however I am not yet clear on the second part of my question (how to find the number of unique occurrences).

Is there a formula or VBA code that could do this?

Comment: You can use wildcards with `COUNTIF` see [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/wildcard-characters-HP005203612.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,"="&"*"&C1&"*")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly for the first part of my question. How would I then count the unique instances of EuropeSpain (i.e. to take into account that "EuropeSpainMadrid" appears twice, the end result should be 2 rather than 3)?

Comment: Manually copy to another column and remove duplicates then use the same formula again.

Comment: I appreciate that that would do the trick, however given the dataset I am using changes often this would be quite manual. Is there no formula that would work?

Comment: There might be VBA solution, add VBA tag to your post.

Comment: Thanks. I will give you an uptick and will wait for other answers before accepting anything...

Answer (score 1):

For without VBA but with some versatility, I suggest with Text in ColumnA (labelled), ColumnB labelled `Flag` and `EuropeSpain` in C1:

```
=FIND(C$1,A2)
```

in B2 copied down.

Then pivot A:B with `Flag` for FILTERS (and `1` selected), Text for ROWS and Count of Text for Sigma VALUES.

Apply Distinct Values if required (and available!), alternatively a formula of the kind:

```
=MATCH("Grand Total",E:E)-4
```

would count uniques.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I am using Excel 2010, so Distinct Values is not available. However in any case I am looking to avoid adding any intermediate steps (i.e. pivot tables, other data sets etc) between my data and the counts. My original solution involved a combination of pivots and concatenated strings, but required manual adjutment each time the dataset changed (which is often).

Comment: Fair enough. Let me amend the question to make it clearer. With regards to the =MATCH("Grand Total",E:E)-4 formula, how does this count uniques? How does this formula work? Understanding it will allow me to adapt it to my exact dataset.